# linux: /home/user's owner is changed to an integer; why?

Tags: linux, filesystems

The owner of the mysql users on my AWS instance has been changed from username to a number. The number is not listed in passwd, group, shadow or gshadow. It appears to be associated with an installed perl moduel, Devel-CheckLib-1.16.

What do these numbers represent? Why would the username folders in /home be changed to be owned by e.g. '1002'?

Joe White

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Precisely because the number is not listed in `/etc/passwd` you’re not seeing a name: There just isn’t one. You should proceed carefully with fixing this so as not to accidentally expose confidential information.

Comment: @Daniel B: These users are system users for mysql.  The directories, ie /home/mysql are essentially empty (except for .bashrc, etc).  How would change the owner back to mysql expose confidential information?  I don't understand.

Comment: You could for example inadvertently make the MySQL database files accessible to more/all users, exposing the data inside that is normally protected by SQL privileges. `chown` isn’t _that_ dangerous, but it will overwrite UID or GID without asking.

Answer (score 3):

A number like `1002` represents the user ID of the user who owns the file. The reason it shows as an ID instead of a username is usually because the system cannot resolve it to an existing user in `passwd`,`shadow`,`group`,etc. You can also use commands like `ls -n` to list all files with IDs instead of names.

This generally happens when the user account got deleted or recreated (with a new ID), or when that file was created by a user with that ID on another system.

In Linux, newly created users get assigned IDs starting with 500 (OS X, RHEL), others start at 1000 (openSUSE, Debian). Your `1002` was likely the 3rd user created on the system, but it depends on where it came from.

Answer (score 2):

This happen when the user who own file or directory do not exist in the system. You run something which change the ownership of this directory. So go back and change the ownership with:

```
chown -R user:group /home/path
```

The other way is to create new user with this ID (1002 in your case)

```
useradd -u 1002 mysql
```

(for example)